# Javascript: Create draggable elements that push each other out of the way

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like to have a series of boxes that can be dragged around in a frame. When when they touch another box, it is pushed out of the way - repelled if you will.

I just don't even know where to start beyond making them draggable!!

Comment: you can start from here https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: Thanks, I have managed this bit - it is making stuff move out of the draggables way that is causing me the headache.

Comment: you can try to check how they making coords detection in snap example, and instead of snap - move your blocks away https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

Comment: oh, actually that's snap param, so you need to write your own i guess

Comment: This is going to be a rather complex answer in the end. There is not currently a way to do this. Let's take one use case, you have an object on the left and you drag it along X toward the right. When the right edge of the object encounters another object, the two should move to the right together, but not overlapping. The Edge Detection alone will be tough. You need to 1) know where the right edge of your object is, 2) left edge of your other object, 3) the offset of the mouse and the right edge of your object, 4) when the edged collide. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment and show you a possible proof of concept, I have created this small bit of code:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/L03rks0y/

**HTML**

```
<div id="move-frame">
  <div id="obj-1" class="drag">
    <span class="top">T: 2</span>
    <span class="left">L: 2</span>
    <span class="bottom">B:</span>
    <span class="right">R:</span>
  </div>
  <div id="obj-2" class="no-drag">
    <span class="top">T: 125</span>
    <span class="left">L: 175</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#move-frame {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.drag,
.no-drag {
  border: 0px solid #666;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
}

.top,
.left,
.bottom,
.right {
  display: block;
  font-size: 85%;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#obj-1 {
  background: #6f6;
}

#obj-2 {
  background: #ccf;
  position: absolute;
  top: 125px;
  left: 175px;
}
```

**jQuery UI**

```
$(function() {
  var stuff = {};

  $(".no-drag").each(function(k, v) {
    var id = $(v).attr("id");
    var top = $(v).position().top;
    var left = $(v).position().left;
    var bottom = top + $(v).height();
    var right = left + $(v).width();
    stuff[k] = {
      id: id,
      top: top,
      left: left,
      bottom: bottom,
      right: right
    };
  });
  console.log(stuff);

  $("#obj-1").draggable({
    containment: '#move-frame',
    drag: function(e, ui) {
      var objW = ui.helper.width();
      var objH = ui.helper.height();
      var objP = ui.position;
      var buffer = 2;

      objP.right = objP.left + objW;
      objP.bottom = objP.top + objH;

      $(this).find(".top").html("T: " + objP.top);
      $(this).find(".left").html("L: " + objP.left);
      $(this).find(".bottom").html("B: " + objP.bottom);
      $(this).find(".right").html("R: " + objP.right);

      $.each(stuff, function(k, v) {
        if (objP.right == v.left - buffer) {
          var $el = $("#" + v.id);
          $el.css("left", v.left + buffer);
          v.left += buffer;
          $el.find(".top").html("T: " + $el.position().top);
          $el.find(".left").html("L: " + $el.position().left);
        }
        if (objP.bottom == v.top - buffer) {
          var $el = $("#" + v.id);
          $el.css("top", v.top + buffer);
          v.top += buffer;
          $el.find(".top").html("T: " + $el.position().top);
          $el.find(".left").html("L: " + $el.position().left);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

There are lots of ways to improve upon this. You can see that it's very easy to drag pas the buffer, yet if moved slowly, you nudge the blue box around with the green box. You can also see some gapping issues, like if you slowly bring the green box over, but are not on the same Y plane, the blue box can still be moved.